# pretty print of nix attrsets

Tags: nix, nixos

when developing in nix i usually use `builtins.trace` for debugging:

## in code

```
a = { foo = "bar"; ... more complex nested attrset ...};
builtins.trace a a;
```

## in nix-repl

using `:p a` on a complex data structure is really hard to read also.

## the problem

however, the output is just a single line without any formating and for complex data structure this is barely usable for debugging.

## the question

is there a pretty print function in nix which does some indentation and adding of newline? or even better colored output?

## ideal output

i'd like to see something like this:

```
default = {
  active = { 
    check_ssl = [
      {
        tags = [ "mycustomtag" ];
        host = "kotalla.de";
        ipv6 = false;
        name = "ssl11";
      }
      {
        tags = [ "mycustomtag" ];
        host = "kotalla.de";
        ipv6 = false;
        name = "ssl2";
      }
    ];
    check_http = [
      {
        host = "kotalla.de";
        port = 80;
        url = "/foo";
        contains = "Labor";
        name = "http";
      }
    ];
    check_ssh = [
      {
        host = "mail.lastlog.de";
        port = 20202;
        name = "ssh";
      }
    ];
  };
```

## my hack

- https://github.com/kamilchm/go2nix/issues/22#issuecomment-347693233

## what i'm aware of:

- https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/832
- https://github.com/Gabriel439/nixfmt

Answer (score 2):

Nixfmt is a popular Nix code formatter:
https://github.com/Gabriel439/nixfmt

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/haskell-nix/hnix/tree/50e63f80afa8323b25b692533e731eea641e56af#parse--print

> To parse a file with hnix and pretty print the result:
>
> `hnix file.nix`

Answer (score 0):

In case this is interesting to any future readers, I made a [fork](https://github.com/MathiasSven/nix-pretty-repl) of Nix that adds pretty printing, but it is only meant to be used for `nix repl`, so the application it exports is `nix-repl`, I still use upstream Nix for everything else. It also has Flakes enabled by default, so it shouldn't bitrot so soon. Though If I keep making use of Nix I plan on merging from upstream every once in a while when there are relevant changes.